# Complex TypeScript circular dependency problem

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I am having a quite complex dependency structure within the data model of my Angular app.

In an abstract form, it looks like this (A -> B means "A imports B"):

[image]

From this structure I get many circular dependencies and it is difficult for me to solve the problem. I already tried to apply the solution mentioned [here](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de): I tried using an `internal.ts` file and exporting all of the classes within that file. When importing any of the classes, I imported them from the `./internal.ts` file again.

Still, the problem persists. The only thing that changes is the form of the error messages:

From

```
Circular dependency detected: C.ts -> D.ts -> E.ts -> C.ts
```

to

```
Circular dependency detected: C.ts -> internal.ts -> C.ts
Circular dependency detected: D.ts -> internal.ts -> D.ts
Circular dependency detected: E.ts -> internal.ts -> E.ts
```

Is there any other way to solve a problem like this?

Answer (score 8):

The solution proposed in the [linked article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) does not eliminate circular dependencies – it merely avoids any disastrous effects they may cause by carefully controlling the load order. To quote:

> The reason that this solves our problem is: *we now have full control
>   over the module loading order*. Whatever the import order in
>   `internal.js` is, will be our module loading order.

Circular dependencies are only problematic and therefore the module load order is only really important if you have modules that evaluate their imports *immediately* as they are loaded – i.e. the imported values are used in the main body of the module:

```
// Foo.js
import { Bar } from "./Bar"

export class Foo {
  getBarClass() {
    return Bar;
  }
}


// Bar.js
import { Foo } from "./Foo"

console.log(Foo.name);           // Foo eval'ed on load :(
export const fooClass = Foo;     // Foo eval'ed on load :(

export class Bar extends Foo {   // Foo eval'ed on load :(
  static fooClass = Foo;         // Foo eval'ed on load :(
  fooClass = Foo;                // Eval'ed only on new Bar()

  static getFooClass() {        
    return Foo;                  // Eval'ed only on Bar.getFooClass()
  }

  getFooClass() {                
    return Foo;                  // Eval'ed only on someBar.getFooClass()
  }
}
```

In this example *Foo.js* does not access `Bar` at load time, only later when `getBarClass` is called. On the other hand, *Bar.js* does access the imported `Foo` multiple times at load time. Therefore, *Bar.js* has to be loaded first.

Circular dependencies cease to be an issue once you no longer access imports immediately at load time:

```
// execute in next tick
setImmediate(() => console.log(Foo.name));

// wrap in function
export const getFooClass = () => Foo;

// wrap in function
export const getBarClass = () => {
  return class Bar extends Foo {
    static fooClass = Foo;
    fooClass = Foo;
  };
};
```

Of course these solutions for delayed evaluation look rather ugly so in the end you may want to go with the carefully coordinated load order after all.

Comment: I simply do not like warnings in my build.  If I toy with the load order, can I make these warnings go away?  Or, is it always possible to have one that can't be solved?

Comment: @DanielKaplan That depends on how your code is structured. I have yet to work on a non-trivial Angular or Node.js project that didn't have them. I usually just turn off the warnings...